# Optimization of finding all pairs between two arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, optimization

The problem: For two arrays of integers A and B I'm trying to find all ( i , j ) such that A[ i ] == B[ j ]

The issue is that I need to run this on millions upon millions of arrays of integers. (each being up to maybe 100 in length) So, speed is the name of the game! I'd like help milking all the speed I can from this, or even just a better overall function.

My approach so far is to virtually sort A and B via:

```py
sorted(range(len(A)), key=lambda k: A[k])
```

It then goes through, raising either i or j (depending on which is lower)
If a match is found between and A and B, it scans A and B until it finds the next value that doesn't match, and treats it as a "matching range"
It then saves the cross product of these ranges as found pairs. 
The code terminates when either:
A and B are at the end of their respective arrays, or when one is at the end and the other is currently pointing to a value that is greater (as it would be impossible to find a pair by scanning farther)

```py
A = [3,7,8,2,1]#Example arrays. Lengths can be different.
B = [4,2,9,3,6,3]#Real arrays will be longer (up to 100).

SortA=sorted(range(len(A)), key=lambda k: A[k]) 
SortB=sorted(range(len(B)), key=lambda k: B[k]) 

solns = []
i = 0
j = 0
done = False

while(not done):
    if(A[SortA[i]] == B[SortB[j]]):

        if(i == len(A) - 1):
            endA = 0
        for m in range(len(A) - i - 1):
            endA = m + 1
            if(A[SortA[i]] != A[SortA[i + m + 1]]):
                endA = m 
                break;

        if(j == len(B) - 1):
            endB = 0
        for n in range(len(B) - j - 1):
            endB = n + 1
            if(B[SortB[j]] != B[SortB[j + n + 1]]):
                endB = n 
                break;

        for r in range(i, i + endA + 1):
            for s in range(j, j + endB + 1):
                solns.append((r,s))

        i = i + endA + 1
        j = j + endB + 1

    else:
        if(A[SortA[i]] < B[SortB[j]]):
            i = i + 1
        else:
            j = j + 1

    if(i == len(A)):
        if(j == len(B)):
            done = True
        else:
            if(A[SortA[len(A)-1]] < B[SortB[j]]):
                done = True
        i = i - 1
    if(j == len(B)):
        if(B[SortB[len(B)-1]] < A[SortA[i]]):
                done = True
        j = j - 1
```

The expected results for A and B in the above code are:

```
Match : (2, 2) Index: (3,1)
Match : (3, 3) Index: (0,3)
Match : (3, 3) Index: (0,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the `==` builtin functions and module like pandas. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1], 'b': [2,3]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1], 'b': [2,3]})
print( (A==B).all().all() )

A = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,-1], 'b': [2,3]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1], 'b': [2,3]})
print( (A==B).all().all() )
```

output:

```
True
False
```